# web scraping table from multiple pages from a search and creating a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I got this code working for the first page and needed the user agent as it didn't work otherwise.

The problem I get is the search brings the first page, but on the second you have "page=2" and continuing so need to scrape all or as much as needed from the search

"https://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels?page=2&minDW=20000&maxDW=300000&type=4"

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

site= "https://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels?type=4&minDW=20000&maxDW=300000"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/70.0.3538.110'}
req = Request(site,headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req) 

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
type(soup)

rows = soup.find_all('tr')
print(rows[:10])

for row in rows:
   row_td = row.find_all('td')
print(row_td)
type(row_td)

str_cells = str(row_td)
cleantext = BeautifulSoup(str_cells, "lxml").get_text()
print(cleantext)

import re

 list_rows = []
      for row in rows:
         cells = row.find_all('td')
         str_cells = str(cells)
         clean = re.compile('<.*?>')
         clean2 = (re.sub(clean, '',str_cells))
         list_rows.append(clean2)
   print(clean2)
   type(clean2)

df = pd.DataFrame(list_rows)
df.head(10)

df1 = df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)
df1.head(10)
```

Output is a Pandas DataFrame

need to scrape all pages to output a large dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this problem ended up getting stuck in my head, so I worked it out.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

hdr={'User-Agent':'Chrome/70.0.3538.110'}

table_dfs={}

for page_number in range(951):
    http= "https://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels?page={}&minDW=20000&maxDW=300000&type=4".format(page_number+1)

    url= requests.get(http,headers=hdr)
    table_dfs[page_number]= pd.read_html(url.text)
```

it will return the first column (vessel) as a nan value. That's the column for the image, ignore it if you don't need it.
the next column will be called 'built' it has the ships name, and type of ship in it. You'll need to .split() to separate them, and then you can replace column(vessel) with the ships name.

If it works for you I'd love to boost my reputation with a nice green check mark.

Comment: Edit on the above. I'm an idiot. there was a space between page= and {}
ssooooo that clearly would return nothing. It's fixed now. That'll pull all the tables from all the pages

Comment: this worked brillantley FYI this small amount of code beats half of the web scraping methods out there and is more advanced in data capture then most

Comment: one thing though how can I concatenate the pages in a simple way

Comment: That's pandas for you. It does tables really well on websites, but idk if there's more capabilities to it or not.
I'd look up pandas concatenate. I know there's a good amount of documentation on it, that should do it... or maybe iterate through and make a pandas df out of all the tables? You'll have to expiriment

Comment: Also, if the code solved the issue that you were posting about you're supposed to mark it, so people know where the solution is when they scroll through.

Comment: would score you but not enough reps yet, also to note the dataframes come as lists not pandas dataframes

Comment: Ive tried this but only gives me a single data frame not the whole lot df1=pd.concat(table_dfs[page_number])

Answer (score 0):

```
rows = soup.find_all('tr')
print(rows[:10])

for row in rows:
    row_td = row.find_all('td')
print(row_td)
type(row_td)
```

^this code above is the same thing as

```
urls=['some list of urls you want to scrape']
table_dfs= [pd.read_html(url) for url in urls]
```

you can crawl through the urls you're looking for and apply that, and then if you want to do something with/to the tables you can just go:

```
for table in table_dfs:
    table + 'the thing you want to do'
```

Note that the in-line for loop of table_dfs is in a list. That means that you might not be able to discern which url it came from if the scrape is big enough. [Pieca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5550835/pieca) seemed to have a solution that could be used to iterate the websites urls, and create a dictionary key. Note that this solution may not apply to every website.

```
url_list = {page_number:"https://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels?page= 
{}&minDW=20000&maxDW=300000&type=4".format(page_number) for page_number 
in list(range(1, 953))}

table_dfs={}
for url in range(1,len(url_list)):
    table_dfs[url]= pd.read_html(url_list[url],header=hdr)
```

Comment: im sort a confused where in my code do you want me to insert this and what di I remove so far ive added the first respondents?        ` url_list = ["https://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels?page={}&minDW=20000&maxDW=300000&type=4".format(page_number) for page_number in list(range(1, 953))]

for url in url_list:
        hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/70.0.3538.110'}
        req = Request(url,headers=hdr)
        page = urlopen(req) `

Comment: I copied and pasted the part of your code that pandas can replace.. it's the first thing in my comment. Also, dunno what the url_list part is in relation to in the above comment.

Comment: but where am I getting the list of urls from as I wont get them if I follow the code as its already on a single page after the first part of the code even If follow the poster below

Comment: It can be a list of urls, or you could apply the same thing to only one URL. The world is your oyster. The above code was advice, combined with pieca seemed it could be a solution. I'll edit above

Comment: thanks though I have to incorporate the header as the site wont respond without a 'User-Agent' on the this code

Comment: Then get the header, and add it in

Comment: yup I get the forbidden error as I need to add the user agent to the code

Comment: well, how do you add the user agent? Figure that out and you have your solution

Comment: sorryman wouldn't be asking you if I knew where in this new code the header needs to be

Comment: im not trying to get the links for the pages but the tables within each page

Comment: I didn't either, I was just trying to prompt you to look at the documentation for pandas.
I added the header to the pd.read_html() code, but I ran it on the website, and it still is throwing up errors.
error 403: forbbiden when. I run it on only one url
and
http error 400: Bad Request. When run on the entire website.
Maybe read_html wasn't the best call after all and you just need to adapt some of the code you've been given to make it into the full set you need, maybe you just need to fix some bugs and it'll work great. Idk, but I can't code it all for you.

Comment: The code Pieca gave you seems like it'll iterate through all the pages. Now all you have to do is figure out how to pull out the data, and use the table_dfs dict to create the full data set